# path cache of bash command

Tags: python, macos, bash

The python script can't been found after uninstalled the old version with ports:

```
 sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents python27
```

But the python2.7 file is in the system path:

```
➜ ~ $ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
➜ ~ $ python2.7 -V
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
➜ ~ $ ll /opt/local/bin/python*
ls: /opt/local/bin/python*: No such file or directory    
➜ ~ $ ll /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    57K 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel   925B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    70B 10 13 20:38 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    57K 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B 10 12 21:47 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
➜ ~ $ /usr/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.5
➜ ~ $ ll /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    34K 10 12 21:47 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

The PATH value is:

```
➜ ~ $ echo $PATH|tr ':' '\n'
/Users/adyliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
/Users/adyliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin
/Users/adyliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
/Users/adyliu/.rvm/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/adyliu/bin
```

I installed python2.7.3 using ports before, so the path of '/opt/local/bin' is before the path of '/usr/bin',
and the python script(python2.7) was in '/opt/local/bin' before I uninstalled this python.

Now my question is why the python script can not been found though the file is in the system path.

```
➜ ~ $ for d in `echo $PATH|tr ':' ' '`;do if [ -x $d/python2.7 ]; then ls -lh $d/python2.7;fi;done
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    70B 10 13 20:38 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
➜ ~ $ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
➜ ~ $ python2.7 -V
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

How to remove the hash cache of a command:

```
➜ ~ $ command -V python2.7
python2.7 is hashed (/opt/local/bin/python2.7)
➜ ~ $ type python2.7
python2.7 is hashed (/usr/bin/python2.7)
➜ ~ $ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
```

---

**Update 1**:

I DO NOT know why the 'python2.7' can been found currectly NOW (10 minites after the question was posted).

```
➜ ~ $ command -V python2.7
python2.7 is hashed (/usr/bin/python2.7)
```

---

**Update 2**:

The 'python2' script still can not been found:

```
➜ ~ $ python2 -V
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
➜ ~ $ python2
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
➜ ~ $ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
➜ ~ $ command -V python2
python2 is hashed (/opt/local/bin/python2)
➜ ~ $ python2 -V
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
➜ ~ $ /usr/bin/python2 -V
Python 2.7.5
➜ ~ $ ll /usr/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    18B 10 13 20:50 /usr/bin/python2 -> /usr/bin/python2.7
➜ ~ $ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.5
➜ ~ $ python2 -V
-bash: /opt/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I find a question like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

Answer (score 0):

First check the size of the file:

```
du -sh /usr/bin/python2
```

May be the files are not there.

Comment: Thanks! The file can been found after clear the the cache of bash command. See the first comment of the question.